# Creating new Object in paint undo-redo example - Android

Tags: android, object, view, android-canvas, paint

I create a sample project about undo-redo paint in ANdroid.

When click each button to change color of paint, i initialize a new Object such as :

```
dp = new DrawingPanel(MainActivity.this, Color.RED);
```

with DrawingPanel dp and color to be set.

But all the paint change to new color although previous one is other color.

How can i fix that problem.

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#A52A2A"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Undo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Undo" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Redo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Redo" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRed"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="RED" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBlue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="BLUE" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnYELLOW"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="YELLOW" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGreen"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="GREEN" />
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#CCC" >
</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();

FrameLayout frmLayout;
DrawingPanel dp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    frmLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
    dp = new DrawingPanel(this, Color.BLACK);
    frmLayout.addView(dp);

    initChangeColor();
    initUndoRedo();

}

private void initUndoRedo() {

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.Undo))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (paths.size() > 0) {
                        undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
                        dp.invalidate();
                    }
                }
            });

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.Redo))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (undonePaths.size() > 0) {
                        paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size() - 1));
                        dp.invalidate();
                    }
                }
            });

}

private void initChangeColor() {

    findViewById(R.id.btnRed).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dp = new DrawingPanel(MainActivity.this, Color.RED);
            frmLayout.addView(dp);
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.btnBlue).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dp = new DrawingPanel(MainActivity.this, Color.BLUE);
            frmLayout.addView(dp);
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.btnYELLOW).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dp = new DrawingPanel(MainActivity.this, Color.YELLOW);
            frmLayout.addView(dp);
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.btnGreen).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dp = new DrawingPanel(MainActivity.this, Color.GREEN);
            frmLayout.addView(dp);
        }
    });

}

public class DrawingPanel extends View implements OnTouchListener {

    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mPaint, circlePaint, outercirclePaint;

    private float xleft, xright, xtop, xbottom;

    public DrawingPanel(Context context, int colorPaint) {
        super(context);

        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        this.setOnTouchListener(this);

        circlePaint = new Paint();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        outercirclePaint = new Paint();

        outercirclePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setColor(colorPaint);

        outercirclePaint.setColor(0x44FFF000);
        circlePaint.setColor(0xAADD5522);
        outercirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);

        outercirclePaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
        mCanvas = new Canvas();
        mPath = new Path();
        paths.add(mPath);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        for (Path p : paths) {
            canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
        }

    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 0;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        mPath = new Path();
        paths.add(mPath);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will also have to save the color into the undo history. I imagine the best way would be to create a class that holds a path and a color and use those. I imagine it could look something like this (but I haven't tested it so don't shoot me if it needs a bit of tweaking).

```
class MyPath extends Path { public int color; }
```

Which makes an extension of the Path class that also has a public variable to hold the color. And then for storing the history you'd use instead:

```
private ArrayList<MyPath> undonePaths = new ArrayList<MyPath>();
private ArrayList<MyPath> paths = new ArrayList<MyPath>();
```

And for each class you just set the color before adding it to the ArrayList.